# In HTTP headers with parameters, are parameter names case-sensitive?

Tags: http-headers

I know HTTP header names themselves are case-insensitive (*that* question has been answered multiple times), but what of parameter names *within* the headers? I'm talking about parts like:

- `charset` within the `Content-Type` header (the *values* for charset ignore case, but does the `charset` keyword itself?)
- `filename` within the `Content-Disposition` header

Would a server be safe in assuming these keywords will always be lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [RFC 7230 HTTP/1.1 Message Syntax and Routing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2) doesn't say anything regarding header field value, you could assume that this value is application defined. As a result, I don't think that you can be sure that this value will *always* be lowercase.